# Show all post for a given category

Tags: wp-query, categories, templates

I want to be able to show all post for a given category using my default category template *category.php*. The problem is the code I'm using sets the specific category ID. So, whenever I click on CAT2... all the post for CAT1 shows. I want it to just show for CAT2 or CAT3... whichever is clicked.

Code:

```
$args = array (
    'cat'            => 1,
    'orderby'        => rand,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category).

Copy your category.php file and rename it.

```
category-{slug}.php – If the category’s slug is news, WordPress will look for category-news.php.
category-{id}.php – If the category’s ID is 6, WordPress will look for category-6.php.
category.php
```

You can also use template_include to [conditionally](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page) display a template

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'category_page_template', 99 );

function category_page_template( $template ) {

if ( is_category()  ) {
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'your-template.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template;
    }
}

return $template;
}
```

Comment: Doing so would mean I have to create a category file for each of my categories, which is a lot. Is this the only option?

Comment: You can also use template_include. See updated answer. If this works, please click to accept the answer.